# Send a large file over tcp connection

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I need to send a few large files to a computer over the internet. As a result I opened the ports that I plan to use on the router and forward the correspoinding ip addresses. anyways let me show you the classes that I have been working on in order to achieve this. This classes work great with small files but sometimes they fail with large files.

here is the code for the server:  (it is a console application)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{

    //server
    class Program
    {
        static Server s;
        public static void mm()
        {
            s = new Server("192.168.0.196");
            s.startServer();
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mm));
           // t.Start();
            mm();
            Console.Read();
            s.disconnect();
        }


    }



    class MyTCP
    {
        protected const int MaxChunkSize = 4096;

        protected Int32 port { get; set; }
        protected string serverIP { get; set; }
        protected TcpClient client { get; set; }
        protected static NetworkStream stream { get; set; }

        protected void sendData(NetworkStream stream, Byte[] data)
        {
            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        protected String receiveData(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            Byte[] data = new Byte[MaxChunkSize];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

            return responseData;
        }

        protected static Byte[] textToBytes(string text)
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        }

        public virtual void disconnect() { }

        public bool isServerConected { get { return client.Connected; } }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class FileProperties 
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string DestPath { get; set; }
        public double FileSize { get; set; }

        public FileAttributes fileAttributes { get; set; }
        public System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity FileSecurity { get; set; }
        public DateTime creationTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastAccessTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastWriteTime { get; set; }   
    }

    class Server: MyTCP
    {
        private System.IO.FileStream _FileStream;
        private static TcpListener server;
        private static bool disconect;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="localAddr">The ip address of the server</param>
        /// <param name="port">on what port the server going to be listening to?</param>
        /// <param name="autoStartServer">start listening for connections now? you may call the startserver() method latter...</param>
        public Server(string localAddr, Int32 port = 13000, bool autoStartServer = false)
        {
            this.port = port;
            this.serverIP = localAddr;

            if (autoStartServer)
                start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start listening for connections
        /// </summary>
        public void startServer()
        {
            start();
        }

        public override void disconnect()
        {
            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            server.Stop();
            disconect = true;
        }


        void start()
        {
            server = null;

            try
            {
                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), port);

                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[MaxChunkSize];
                String data = null;

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (disconect==false)
                {
                    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");




                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    stream = client.GetStream();



                    int i;
                    try
                    {
                        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                        {


                            // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                            if (data.ToUpper().Contains("<sendFile>".ToUpper()))
                            {
                                receiveFile(bytes);
                            }



                            continue;


                        }
                    }
                    catch { }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
            }


            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }


        void receiveFile(Byte[] bytes)
        {
            // send 1
            sendData(stream, textToBytes("<1>"));

            // receive 2
            int length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            byte[] tempA = new byte[length];
            for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
                tempA[k] = bytes[k];

            Stream ms = new MemoryStream(tempA);
            FileProperties p = new FileProperties();
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());

            try
            {
                p = (FileProperties)x.Deserialize(ms);

                if (Directory.Exists(p.DestPath))
                {
                    //send 3
                    sendData(stream, textToBytes("<3>"));
                }
                else
                {
                    //send 3
                    sendData(stream, textToBytes("<no>"));
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //send 3
                sendData(stream, textToBytes("<no>"));
                return;
            }



            int i;

            string temp = Path.Combine(new string[]{ p.DestPath, p.FileName + ".temp"});

            _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(temp, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    if (i == 11 & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i).ToUpper().Equals("</sendFile>".ToUpper()))
                    {
                        _FileStream.Close();

                        Console.WriteLine("D!");

                        File.SetAttributes(temp, p.fileAttributes);
                        File.SetAccessControl(temp, p.FileSecurity);
                        File.SetCreationTime(temp, p.creationTime);
                        File.SetLastAccessTime(temp, p.lastAccessTime);
                        File.SetLastWriteTime(temp, p.lastWriteTime);

                        if(File.Exists(temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 4)))
                            File.Delete(temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 4));

                        File.Move(temp, temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 4));


                        //sendData(stream, textToBytes("<done>"));

                        Console.WriteLine("Done!");

                        return;
                    }
                    _FileStream.Write(bytes, 0, i);

                }



            return;

        }
    }
}
```

and the code for my client is:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;


namespace WpfApplication23sdfd
{

    [Serializable]
    public class FileProperties 
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string DestPath { get; set; }
        public double FileSize { get; set; }

        public FileAttributes fileAttributes { get; set; }
        public System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity FileSecurity { get; set; }
        public DateTime creationTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastAccessTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastWriteTime { get; set; }
    }

    abstract class MyTCP
    {
        protected const int MaxChunkSize = 4096;

        protected Int32 port { get; set; }
        protected string serverIP { get; set; }
        protected TcpClient client { get; set; }
        protected static NetworkStream stream { get; set; }

        protected void sendData(NetworkStream stream, Byte[] data)
        {

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.
        }

        protected String receiveData(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            Byte[] data = new Byte[MaxChunkSize];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

            return responseData;
        }

        protected static Byte[] textToBytes(string text)
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        }

        public virtual void disconnect() { }

        public bool isServerConected { get { return client.Connected; } }
    }

    //client
    class Client: MyTCP
    {



        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serverIP">the ip address of the server</param>
        /// <param name="port">through what port is the connection going to be established</param>
        public Client(string serverIP, Int32 port = 13000, bool autoConnect = false)
        {
            this.port = port;
            this.serverIP = serverIP;

            if (autoConnect)
                connect();
        }


        public bool connect()
        {
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("connect");

            // Create a TcpClient.
            // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
            // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
            // combination.
            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream = client.GetStream();

                return true;


            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public override void disconnect()
        {
            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }

        static void ConnectOld(String server, Byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.
                Int32 port = 13000;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);



                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);



                // Receive the TcpServer.response.

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }

        public void sendFile(string file, string destPath = "c:\\")
        {

            //let server know what you are going to be doing...
            sendData(stream, textToBytes("<sendFile>"));

            FileProperties p = new FileProperties { 
                creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(file), 
                fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(file), 
                FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(file), 
                lastAccessTime = File.GetLastAccessTime(file), 
                lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(file),
                 DestPath = destPath,
                 FileName = Path.GetFileName(file)
            };


            // receive 1
            if (!receiveData(stream).ToUpper().Contains("<1>".ToUpper()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error comunicating with server");
                return;
            }

            // send object p to server
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
            x.Serialize(stream, p); // send 2

            //recieve 3
            if (!receiveData(stream).ToUpper().Contains("<3>".ToUpper()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error incorrect parameters sent to server");
                return;
            }


            System.IO.FileStream streamFile = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);



            while (true)
            {
                byte[] chunk = new byte[MaxChunkSize];

                int index = 0;
                // There are various different ways of structuring this bit of code.
                // Fundamentally we're trying to keep reading in to our chunk until
                // either we reach the end of the stream, or we've read everything we need.
                while (index < chunk.Length)
                {
                    int bytesRead = streamFile.Read(chunk, index, chunk.Length - index);


                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (bytesRead < MaxChunkSize)
                    {
                        byte[] temp = new byte[bytesRead];

                        for (var i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                            temp[i] = chunk[i];

                        chunk = temp;
                    }


                    index += bytesRead;
                }
                if (index != 0) // Our previous chunk may have been the last one
                {
                    sendData(stream,chunk); // index is the number of bytes in the chunk
                }
                if (index != chunk.Length) // We didn't read a full chunk: we're done
                {

                    sendData(stream, textToBytes("</sendFile>".ToUpper()));

                    //receiveData(stream);//wait recall missing to check results

                    return;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

the way I instantiate the client class is by providing the IP address of the server as:

```
Client c = new Client("192.168.0.196");
c.sendFile(@"A:\Users\Tono\Desktop\a.mp4");
```

the server has to be running first before executing that code.

I don't know why is so complicated to send a file over the internet using sockets. I don't konw WCF that's why I been loosing a lot of time creating this classes. Maybe there are already some built in classes that will enable me to send files over the internet to a different computer. I know just the basics of networking thereofore it will be nice if I could do it with a simple class. I don't undersatnd why my classes do not work all the time? if I increase the buffer size will my classes be more efficient? do I have to wait or pause my program a little bit before sending more bytes? It will be nice if someone can tell me what is wrong with this classes. They work nice with small files but with large files sometimes it does not work...

Comment: Consider using PacketProtocol 
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few issues that I can see immediately. The one that may be causing your program to only work some of the time is the fact that sending via TCP will not guarantee that every `send` will result in an identically-sized `receive` on the other side.

Your protocol seems to assume it will, because you're waiting for a read of exactly 11 bytes for the `</sendFile>`, whereas it could be received in multiple separate reads. E.g.: "[file data...]". If this happens, your code will not correctly finish.

It's also worth noting that the ASCII encoding is 7-bit, and so binary files (such as the MP4) will be received incorrectly (even if you fix the above). If it is binary data, you should not attempt to convert it to a string, but instead write it to file directly from the `byte[]`.

If you wish to contine down this route (rather than using the many existing file transfer systems already available as mentioned in another answer) then you may also want to change your protocol so that instead of delimiting the file with `<sendFile>...</sendFile>`, you send the file's length initially, which will allow you to send files that may contain one of these special tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your second paragraph is where my problem lies. I need to figure a way to let the server know that the transfer is done so that it can start listening for other commands. Moreover i split each file on chunks because i get a memory error when placing a large file to a byte array.

Comment: And my code is not well organized... I do not write ascii chars to the file that i am tranfering :)

Comment: iridum now it works. I wait a few seconds before sending "</sendFile>" and I also increased the chunk size and it works great. how can I know if the stream is being used or if the client is sending bytes? It will be nice if I can know that so that I don't have to wait a few seconds before sending "</sendFile>" and instead wait for the stream to be 'idle' in order to send "</sendFile>" and make my code more efficient...

Answer (score 13):

Here is my code to send a large file.
Some tips:

- Check your buffer size. If it's too big it will fail.
- Socket flags. The partial flag works the best.
- Socket timeout is needed due to the transfer time.

Client :

```
string IPAddress = "";
int Port = 500;

string Filename = @"C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\TT.zip";

        
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = null;
byte[] header = null;


FileStream fs = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open);
bool read = true;

int bufferCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)fs.Length / (double)bufferSize));



TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(IPAddress, Port);
tcpClient.SendTimeout = 600000;
tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 600000;

string headerStr = "Content-length:" + fs.Length.ToString() + "\r\nFilename:" + @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\" + "test.zip\r\n";
header = new byte[bufferSize];
Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(headerStr), header, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(headerStr).Length);

tcpClient.Client.Send(header);

for (int i = 0; i < bufferCount; i++)
{
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int size = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                                                 
    tcpClient.Client.Send(buffer,size,SocketFlags.Partial);
}

tcpClient.Client.Close();

fs.Close();
```

Server :

```
int Port = 500;

TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
listener.Start();


Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();

int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = null;
byte[] header = null;
string headerStr = "";
string filename = "";
int filesize = 0;


header = new byte[bufferSize];

socket.Receive(header);

headerStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(header);


string[] splitted = headerStr.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string s in splitted)
{
    if (s.Contains(":"))
    {
        headers.Add(s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(":")), s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":") + 1));
    }    
}
//Get filesize from header
filesize = Convert.ToInt32(headers["Content-length"]);
//Get filename from header
filename = headers["Filename"];

int bufferCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)filesize / (double)bufferSize));


FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

while (filesize > 0)
{
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int size = socket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.Partial);

    fs.Write(buffer, 0, size);

    filesize -= size;
}

fs.Close();
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: +1 thank you it was very useful ..  
note that you have to remove trailing "\0" from headers before using them in the server when receive them .... I used (header.Replace("\0", string.Empty))

Comment: Why it would failed if buffer size too big?

Comment: Is your example valid if I want that a client download a file FROM the server? I'm a little noob, I'm trying to modify your example to get that behavior (Synching files from server TO clients). Thanks!

Comment: This code is not good. It may fail because if the connection is slow the server may receive part of the file on the header and thus lose that when writing to the actual file!

Answer (score 5):

Sending files / directories over sockets is not trivial. I would recommend using some file transfer library (over sockets, or maybe higher level protocol, i.e. rsync, ftp, http, etc), rather than trying to code the thing from scratch.

After skimming over the code - try sending a large file containing some uniform content (filled with '0's or something). If it would pass through - your xml thing doesn't work.

Comment: yeah you are right I will start looking for some libraries. the xml serialization just saves me time. instead of passing several strings, it enables me to pass an object.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are doing is correct. The main point I could suggest for improvement is setting the `MaxChunkSize` to a larger value, as much as 65000. This will enable the socket code to handle any fragmentation, which will be much more efficient than any splitting you will do by yourself.

Also, you are aware to the fact that sending a large file should take some time. At a 100 Mbit LAN, the bandwidth would be (theoretically) 12.5 MByte per second. Thus sending a 700 MByte file will still take 56 seconds. Of course that the actual throughput depends and many factors in the network and the computers and network hardware involved, so it would be expected to be slower.

Finally, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (or any other sniffer program) is the most basic and invaluable tool in the networking programmer toolbox. Use it on both the server and the client to see how the TCP packets are transmitted, to see if you can identify any causes for the slow trasnfer.