# How to set a local offline LAN multiplayer game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lan

I'm doing a presentation of a 3 person multiplayer unity game.
How, with a LAN cables local connection (and no internet), can I transfer the data (using C#)?
I just need to know when all the players have finished their stages...

When I searched the subject all I found was "Network.Connect" to Connect to a specified host (ip or domain name) and server port, or UNet "Network Discovery" and they are both deprecated....

Comment: I'm not sure what options Unity has available, but don't forget you're using C# (and .NET). Networking exists in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has a wide range anwser.

you can create a multi connection in any network such as offline lan or internet one.
with **socket programming** that exist in very languages and game makers like unity.
yes you can transfer any data with tcp or udp sockets.

for searching for other players you can use multi ways . one way is that use one app in specified ip for server that other client send and get information to it . second way is that search for all pc in lan range and send a message to identity.

a c# sample for transfer text :
[Server Client send/receive simple text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182751/server-client-send-receive-simple-text)

Send LargeFile over Tcp :
[Send a large file over tcp connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185676/send-a-large-file-over-tcp-connection)

Unity transfer image : [unity - Transfer image from server to clients using tcp sockets. Need help in code alterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148641/unity-transfer-image-from-server-to-clients-using-tcp-sockets-need-help-in-co)

Unity Simple Socket : [Simple socket server in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526332/simple-socket-server-in-unity/36526634)